# Samesite and Secure for 3rd party cookies as of Feb 20th

Tags: javascript, java, cookies, magnolia, samesite

I've recently encountered a problem and I'm wondering: is it possible to set the 3rd party cookies Samesite and Secure attributes from the frontend of a project? I'm using MagnoliaCMS (a Java based CMS) and the 3rd party cookies are mostly google and youtube cookies. Is there a way to modify said cookies through JS? For example:

```
document.cookie = "name=value ; Samesite=None ; Secure " ;
```

The project is hosted on a server to which I do not have access to, is it possible it's a problem that's supposed to be solved on the server side instead? My research so far shows it's mostly involved with the HTTP headers that are handled server-side when using Node in those cases. However, I'm aware I'm not using Node, nor do I find a trace of the headers being handled in my CMS's backend (Java).

Answer (score 0):

Hey all turns out you can actually do this without the need of using JAVA/Spring.

Just when the document is loaded you need to specify your cookies.

```
document.cookie = "name=value ; Samesite=None; Domain=domainname.com ; Secure " ;
```